# combining hashCode() and equals() is faster?

Tags: java, string, equals, hashcode

So I  am doing some research on fastest on comparing strings and found this code:

```
if (s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode() && s1.equals(s2))
```

My question is: Why is it faster? Cause what I think is that it take more computer cycle than just saying with no &&.

Comment: it is faster than what?

Comment: than saying if (s1.equals (s2))

Comment: Is it faster to compare two people's fingerprints or DNA?

Comment: Do keep in mind that `&&` means that if the left side is false the right side will not be evaluated.  (I'm sure most here know this, but it seemed appropriate to point it out.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java strings cache their hash codes - so if the hash codes are equal, the strings are *very likely* to be equal. A full equality check could take much longer, if the strings are the same length and only differ near the very end. (The implementation of `equals` in `String` first checks the lengths, before it looks at the actual code units.)

On the other hand, that requires the hash code to be computed - if it hasn't already been computed, that will be O(n) in the length of the string, whereas two strings of unequal length can be compared for equality very quickly.

So *if* you know that the strings have already been hashed *and* you're expecting there to be lots of strings with the same length<sup>1</sup>, this is an optimization - otherwise it could make things slower. I wouldn't use it in general purpose-code though - and I would add a comment explaining the reason for it, too.

---

<sup>1</sup> *And* you don't already know that the hash codes are equal through some other mechanism, as per supercat's comment below - I'd say this is a corner case on a corner case though.

Comment: Although unless it's been hiding within your code the whole time, the chances of a string having been previously hashed are pretty high even if you didn't do it.

Comment: @ruakh: Strings in particular.  See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29 for example.  Some other classes almost certainly do it too...ie: it's not the JVM doing it.

Comment: @ruakh: It's an implementation detail in `java.lang.String`. And it would never be invalidated for `String`, as strings are immutable in Java.

Comment: @cHao: What makes you think that? Strings are used for all kinds of things, and many of them will never need to be hashed.

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for the edit; sorry for not being clear beforehand.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : "Java caches hash codes - so if the hash codes are equal, the strings are very likely to be equal."???.. Or is it the other way around- "Java caches hash codes - so if the hash codes are not equal, the strings cannot be equal." , so, the second part (.equals() ) will not be called everytime (as ruchira suggests in his answer..)

Comment: @JonSkeet: If that string was ever used as a key in a hash table, or was interned, or was in an object that had *its* hash code checked for some reason...etc etc.  There are a bunch of cases where a hash code might be generated, even if you never directly ask for it.

Comment: @TheLostMind: The hash codes *can* be equal without the strings being equal, but that would be a pretty rare occurrence. The string hash code is good enough to avoid having frequent collisions.

Comment: @cHao: Compared with an interned string in what sense? Just using `equals` won't do it, as far as I know. And most strings *aren't* used as keys in hash tables, at least in the code I use. Consider a data entity with 10 strings in (first name, last name, address line 1, address line 2, zip code etc) - how many of those are likely to end up being hashed?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Please pardon my ignorance.. "So if you know that the strings have already been hashed, this is an optimization" . My question is - If the object (String) exists, then it must have a hash code (it must be hashed right?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: If they contribute to the result of `equals()`, their hash codes ought to factor in to the object's hash code.

Comment: @TheLostMind: Nope. A string can exist without being hashed. It's only hashed when it's used as a key in a hash table (either as a member of the table, or being used to fetch *from* the table) or a few other cases.

Comment: @cHao: You're assuming that something is asking the entity itself for its hash code - and that it overrides `equals` to start with. That's a big assumption. The majority of strings in the code *I* write are never hashed.

Comment: @user2844805: You can't *just* use the hash code - there can be multiple unequal strings with the same hash code. It's just a first filtering operation - two strings with different hash codes *can't* be equal.

Comment: You forgot one more requirement for the "optimization" being beneficial: there must be a significant likelihood of unequal strings having unequal hash codes.  Consider, e.g., an immutable class `Foo` which encapsulates a string `name` and an integer `number`, and computes hash value `name.hashCode() + number*14711;`.  If a `HashSet<Foo>` compares two instances `o1` and `o2`, and `equals` has determined that `o1.number == o2.number`, then comparing `o1.name.hashCode()` and `o2.name.hashCode()` isn't apt to help much, *since they're going to be equal whether the names are or not*.

Comment: @supercat: While that's true, that presupposes you have two such instances. It's not hard to *find* distinct strings with equal hash codes, but I'd be surprised to see it come up very regularly in a real application. Yes, in the case you've shown comparing the hash code wouldn't do anything useful - but then you wouldn't be trying to compare *strings* for equality optimally, you'd be trying to compare `Foo` instances for equality, and that difference in context is relevant. Still, will add it to the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Outside deliberate denial-of-service attacks it's rare to have a huge number of strings with the same hash code (occasional collisions are pretty common, but harmless).  My point was that in many of the cases where testing hash codes is apt to be helpful (e.g. finding items in a `HashSet<T>`) it's likely that outside code will already do so.  The OP didn't say where the code was found, but the most likely scenario where it could be helpful would be an `equals` method for an class which encapsulates data in a fixed-length string and would often be stored in hash tables.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your edit looks good.  You make your main point--that only in very rare situations is pre-checking the hashcode useful--better than the other answers.  I was merely wishing to suggest that cases where it's beneficial are even rarer than you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it's faster. If it were it would have been included in String.equals implementation. Note that the first String.hashCode call is costly. Imagine you need only String.equals but you calculate hash on both Strings. It would rather be a performance kill.

Comment: +1. `String.equals` can certainly tell whether both strings' hash-codes have been cached.

Comment: It could, but it doesn't in the implementation I'm looking at. It would only be useful in a fairly specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

`s1.hashCode () == s2.hashCode () && s1.equals (s2)` here if left hand side of this expression not true that will not going to evaluate right hand side. Then that will be help this to be some fast.But not always.

Comment: But if they are equal, both halves of the expression have to be evaluated, which would be slower. I suppose you might use this if you expected the vast majority of the comparisons to be equal, but that would be implementation-dependent.

Comment: @BillHorvathII: The hash code check is only helpful when a string is checked for equality against other strings which have the same length and have a long matching prefix, but nonetheless have different hash values.  In most programs, such situations will be rare if they occur at all, but in some programs they may occur frequently.  Note, however, that many cases where this kind of optimization might be helpful might be helped even further by using an alternate string-hash method instead of `getHashCode()`.

Comment: @supercat: Like I said, it'd be implementation dependent. :)

Answer (score 0):

The general contract for the equals(Object) and hashCode() methods states that objects which are equal will always return hashcodes that are equal. Ergo, it's hard to see how comparing hashcodes *and* equality would gain you anything in terms of performance, particularly where strings are the object in question.

(Side note: Make sure s1 and s2 aren't null before you call this as written.)